# How to include respond_to when you don't inherit from ApplicationController in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require, actionpack

I have an API controller in a Rails 4.1.2 app that does not inherit from Application controller.  I'm trying to include the respond_to method and get a method undefined error....So then I required actionpack at the top like below:

```
require 'action_pack'

class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  version 1

  doorkeeper_for :all
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with current_user.as_json(except: :password_digest)
  end
end
```

and I still get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `respond_to' for Api::V1::UsersController:Class):
```

But the respond_to method is part of the MODULE ActionController::MimeResponds::ClassMethods which can be found under the action_pack folder in a subdirectory if I open up the actionpack gem source code.

EDIT:

I should also mention Api::ApiController has a parent RocketPants::Base since I'm using the rocketpants api gem ... The gem's author states on his README: "RocketPants only includes the bare minimum to make apis. In the near future, it may be modified to work with ActionController::Base for the purposes of better compatibility with other gems."

I'm particularly interested in how to get access to the action_pack methods/libraries (if it's possible) in a standalone fashion, the way you can when you include activesupport.

Answer (score 5):

Simply make your `Api::ApiController` (or its parent if there is one) inherit from `ActionController::Base`

---

Good thing you mention you are using RocketPants! A quick look at their github page confirm that it is already derivated from `ActionController::Base`. That renders my previous answer incorrect.

So it seems you don't need to call `respond_to` and that instead of `respond_with` you should use `expose`, but well it's a blink guess. You should follow their documentation

Comment: Thanks Benjamin...So I should mention Api::ApiController also has a parent RocketPants::Base since I'm using the rocketpants api gem ...  should I make a "grandparent" controller and have Api::ApiController inherit from ActionController::Base?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, so in this case you don't think you can use include 'action_pack' and use respond_to?  (I'm trying to see if I can use actionpack in a standalone way the way you can use activesupport for the future).

Comment: I think that you don't need it, and that's the whole purpose of using RocketPants. But really I can be wrong cause I never used RocketPants, it's what it seems from the outside. Sorry I can't help more

Answer (score 5):

Also check your rails version. In Rails 4.2 and up, the respond_to syntax has been moved into the 
[responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders).

Gemfile:

```
gem 'responders'
```

Console:

```
bundle install
rails g responders:install
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw this error `ActionController::RoutingError: undefined method 'respond_to'` while I was using [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api). After switching `ActionController::API` to `ActionController::Base` my error was resolved. This also fixed `active_model_serializers` failing to wrap `render :json` automatically with the corresponding serializers to my models. I may log this as an issue with the gem.

Comment: Did you log this issue with the gem? I'm also facing the similar error.

Comment: @Inquisitive I wouldn't log it at this point as `rails_api` has been rolled into Rails. (Just leaving that note here for posterity.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include (at least) the ActionController::RespondWith module.