# Impossible to run a Rails console on heroku with Attachinary: undefined method `respond_to' for Attachinary::CorsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

I am running a Rails app uploading images with a Cloudinary/Attachinary configuration.Locally, everything is fine, my app run and I can upload pictures to Cloudinary. I can push on Heroku, migrations are OK, config vars too but the app crashes with that error:

```
<class:CorsController>': undefined method `respond_to' for Attachinary::CorsController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Some help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: maybe try `bundle update`

Comment: Attachinary solves this problem since this commit: https://github.com/assembler/attachinary/commit/685a01e0f96fc66139f0e9e058f0f11a42248d5e You need to get the master version of the gem `gem 'attachinary', github: 'assembler/attachinary'`

Answer (score 1):

Just found this: [How to include respond_to when you don't inherit from ApplicationController in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877075/how-to-include-respond-to-when-you-dont-inherit-from-applicationcontroller-in-r) and it solves my problem.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'responders'
```

then

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g responders:install
```